# Sonar Complains about variable declaration..Cant we use "_"?

Tags: java, sonarqube, naming-conventions

```
private String producer_queueName = "cn";
```

> Name 'consumer_queueName' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

Whats wrong with using `_`?
Does Java not allow you to use `_` for any variable?

I want to use `_`. How can I get rid of this error:

```
must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
```

Comment: First you showed us `producer_queueName` variable and a message about `consumer_queueName`. In either case it is not illegal to use `_` in your identifiers but it is against common practice and standards. Java uses `camelCase`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a warning from Sonar telling you that you are not conforming to java standards. In Java, it is standard to use camelCase for private variables. _ should only be used for static final variables.

For example:

```
//Conforming private variable with camelCase
private String producerQueueName = "cn";

//Conforming private static final variable with "_"
private static final String PRODUCER_QUEUE_NAME = "cn";
```

Sonar isn't telling you that you *can't* do what you're doing, just that you aren't complying with the standards. This might make it harder for someone else to read your code.

See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for more details about java naming conventions.

If you wish to disable the rule in Sonar, you will need to disable the rule in the Quality profile you are using. See [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) for the documentation on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar messages are not errors.

The underlying rules are kind of best practices, but not everybody agrees to all of them. Each team should discuss which rules are important and which should be deactivated.

For this particular rule, I think most Java programmers would think this is an important one, because (as stjepano already mentioned) this is part of the Java naming conventions (e.g. camel case with first letter lower case for variable names, camel case with first letter capitalized for class names, etc.). This makes it far more easier to read someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blCW1.png)

If you have this type of error `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` what you should do is rename your variable without Characters as an example the `_`

For this case it would be:

```
private String producerQueueName = "cn";
```